# Отсутствуют лог-файлы: dmesg, syslog, auth.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, логирование

Cодержимое директории /var/log :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, отсутствуют нужные лог-файлы. Вопрос, почему они отсутствуют в этой директории и как их получить?

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они не нужны. Всё это логируется в journald. Но если хочется их вернуть, то

```
systemctl enable rsyslog
systemctl start rsyslog
```